# How to set Brazillian Portuguese localization in iTunes Connect

Tags: localization, app-store-connect

I'm a bit confused on how to set up my Brazillian Portuguese meta data localization in iTunes Connect. First off, in xCode when I add the localization I have the option of Portuguese or Portuguese (Portugal) from which I obviously choose Portuguese. Then, in iTunes Connect when I want to add a new meta data localization, my choices are Brazillian Portuguese and Portuguese. My ultimate goal is so that my Brazillian Portuguese translation is shown to users in Portugal and Brazil, so should I simply choose "Portuguese" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not further defined two set of translations for Portuguese and Brazilian Portuguese, you should place the same Portuguese translations to both languages.

I believe iTunes connect does not have any language fallback betweem these 2 languages, as they are regarded them as 2 separated languages.

For more information, you can have a look at [this article](http://support.oneskyapp.com/support/articles/89611-how-to-add-localized-app-description-on-itunes) for useful tips about iTunes connect localization.

Comment: Yeah figured out this is correct. What's weird is in your binary, when you do these two languages in localizable.strings, if one is missing it will default to the other. So kind of the opposite behavior of iTunes Connect.